# What's the goal of banning Tobacco?

Tags: policy

According to [this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-59589775) New Zealand is banning completely Tobacco for the new generations. The people behind the decision claim it is for health reason. However the current policy adopted by the developed countries and also some developing countries is working, [the number of smokers all over the world is decreasing](https://www.who.int/publications/i/item/who-global-report-on-trends-in-prevalence-of-tobacco-use-2000-2025-third-edition), so why change it?

The approach taken by the legislators completely disregards the facts. Most of people started smoking in their teens even though selling and giving cigarettes to minors has been illegal for a long time in many countries and the same situation will be pushed to the extreme. About 8 years from now there will be a lot of of people in the age range between 18 and 22 who are being told that they are considered adults, but they are not allowed to smoke while all other people they see around are. How they will react seems quite obvious. So, we already can see that the assumption this policy is based on is just a slogan.

Furthermore the plan is to turn the ban on sales into a full prohibition in the long term, but prohibition often doesn't work, alcohol prohibition in the USA didn't last long and cannabis is another example of failed prohibition that is leading many countries to reconsider their policy.

It does not seem possible that the legislators in New Zealand didn't take these facts into account. The simplistic assumptions they made are too naive to be credible, the only real difference that we could see in the future is that young ones will have again the thrill of the forbidden thing.

This law is clearly designed to fail.

Considering all of this can peoples' health be really the reason for this law? What else could be the goal?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the current policy adopted by the developed countries and also some developing countries is working"*? Do you mean tobacco taxes? If those are working then doesn't that refute your comparison with alcohol prohibition? Perhaps a more interesting question would be what scientific considerations, if any, the government has presented to support their decision for this plan? Now it very much comes across as a push question suggesting there's some hidden agenda.

Answer (score 2):

> Another thing to take into account is that prohibition often doesn't work, alcohol prohibition in the USA didn't last long and cannabis is another example of failed prohibition that is leading many countries tovreconsider their policy. It does not seem possible that the legislators in New Zealand didn't take this facts into account. Furthermore now they can give to their young ones the thrill of the forbidden thing.

New Zealand's policy isn't outright prohibition - it is prohibiting sales to people below a certain age, and that age will increase every year. In other words, if they ban people currently below the age of 14 from buying cigarettes today, next year it will be people currently below the age of 15, and so on. Therefore if you are above 14 and currently smoke, you can continue to smoke.

Will it work? Only someone with a crystal ball will know, but New Zealand health minister Dr. Ayesha Verrall [says](https://www.newsnationnow.com/health/health-headlines/new-zealands-plan-to-end-smoking-a-lifetime-ban-for-youth/) (emphasis mine):

> New Zealand’s approach to ban the next generation from tobacco smoking hasn’t been tried elsewhere, she said.
>
> **But she said studies have shown youth sales decrease when minimum ages are raised**. In the U.S., the federal minimum age to buy tobacco products was raised from 18 to 21 two years ago.

If you believe the unnamed studies, then you can see how their plan is intended to work. By having fewer youth sales, fewer people start smoking, and there's less need to worry about quitting (which is very difficult for smokers).

I see no reason to think the move is not because New Zealand's leadership want to improve their citizens' health.

> The number of smokers all over the world is decreasing, so why change it?

Evidently policymakers in New Zealand don't think it's decreasing fast enough.

Comment: "If you believe the unnamed studies, then you can see how their plan is intended to work. By having fewer youth sales, fewer people start smoking," Most of people start smoking in their youth, notwithstanding the fact that selling and giving cigarettes to minors has been illegal for a long time in many countries. Your claim is based on a false assumption that disregards the facts.

Comment: @FluidCode I didn't make any claim. I just relayed what the NZ health minister said. Plus, if you are making that comment I think it's clear this is a push question, so -1.

Comment: I assumed it was your claim because it was not formatted as a quote. In any case it does not matter who said it, what matters is that it is false.  Furthermore I don't like to personalise and link the arguments to the persons to imply some bias.